# Visual studio 2013 and Azure web app

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs, web-deployment

I want setup my 2012 TFS project so that when I check-in my code, TFS should deploy the project to Web app on Azure using the publish profile file. Is that doable ? how ? thank you.

Comment: You can configure this automatically from within Azure. Have you tried this? Has anything gone wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes, I have tried that with Visual Studio Online and Azure. Does that work the same way with TFS 2012 and Azure ? Also, I have a virtual directory (setup as Application) in my Azure web app. On every code check-in I want to deploy to that virtual directory.

Comment: The steps are the same. You need the Build Definition that is created in your VSO project. If you download that to your TFS server and use it in a build everything should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's possible. Check out the following article on the Azure website:

**Continuous delivery with Visual Studio Online in Azure**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/

It covers the following steps:

- Step 1: Create a team project
- Step 2: Check in a project to source control
- Step 3: Connect the project to Azure
- Step 4: Trigger a rebuild and redeploy your project
- Step 5: Redeploy an earlier build
- Step 6: Change the Production deployment
- Step 7: Run unit tests

Hope that helps! :)